# Upgrade my amcharts flash to amcharts javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, amcharts

I'm using amcharts flash at the moment. see here: http://www.myinvestmentdecision.com.au/Sample-Results

I want to change that to use the javascript charts instead so that It will work on apple devices, and so that it will print nicely in modern browsers (most of which can't print flash at all, or print it looking very clunky)

My question is this - I use XML to produce the flash graphs. The data is in a variety of xml feeds. Is there a way for me to use this in the javascript charts as well? From the example I saw here: http://blog.amcharts.com/2011/05/getting-started-part-2.html
They show code that has a big array for the data

```
var chartData = [

     {country: "USA", litres: "19544"},

     {country: "Japan", litres: "5455"},

     {country: "France", litres: "2313"},

     {country: "Germany", litres: "2208"},

     {country: "UK", litres: "2057"},

     {country: "India", litres: "1771"},

     {country: "Russia", litres: "1495"},

     {country: "South Korea", litres: "1281"},

];
```

That would be an extra processing step for me, one which I'm not totally keen on.
If it has to be done then okay, my question changes to, how do i do it?

[Here's an example of my XML](http://pastebin.com/cq2ivn9z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is exactly the same way using xml for javascript, i use javascript charts and i take data from postgresql then generate a xml with php and use the xml to charge data in a amcharts.
My apologies for my english, is not so good. :)